# Hibernate @OneToMany Mapping fetching records

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, hibernate-onetomany, hibernate-jpa

I have googled everywhere but unable to get what I need 
Unable to get the respective output.
I have two classes Employee and EmployeeLocation and their respective tables in SQL.

This is my table For EmployeeLocation Table multiple emp_ids

[image: Table]

MyScenario -> In employee table id is the primary key and have unique values but in EmployeeLocation table I have that Employee id as **emp_id** in EmployeeLocation Table which is not unique which is appearing multiple time.

I am trying to achieve @OnetoMany Association but not succeeding.
Help Appreciated.

```
class Employee {
     private integer id;
     @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="empId")
     private List<EmployeeLocation> employeeLocation;
     //getters and setters
}

 class EmployeeLocation {
      private integer id;
      private integer emp_id; 
      // emp_id is a primary key in employee table
      //fields  getters and setters 
}
```

Comment: Why is not succeeding? Do you receive some error or don't know how to do it?

Comment: Getting null Object of EmployeeLocation in Employee Object

Comment: How do you query it @GauravMasand ?

Comment: try `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="emp_id")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact in the `EmployeeLocation` you need to have a reference to the mapped `Employee` and not the `emp_id`, because the mapping is based on the entity.

So that's what you need :

**EmplyeeLocation**:

```
class EmployeeLocation {

      @Id
      private int id;
      @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      private Employee emp; 
}
```

**Employee:**

```
class Employee {

     @Id
     private int emp_id;
     @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="emp")
     @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
     private List<EmployeeLocation> employeeLocation;
}
```

**Note:**

- Don't miss to specify the `@Id` annotation for the `id` fields so the
  the entities can be mapped correctly.
- Pay attention to the types you are using, `Java` is case sensitive, there's no `integer` type, it's either `int` or `Integer`.
- Note that it's recommended to use `Set` instead of `List` in
  hibernate mappings for `OneToMany`.

Comment: This is just a demo code.I have my project where i am facing such problem. I know hibernate but i am stuck in this problem. I dont want  to perform manipulation i just want to get the data.I want to get the Employee data and along with i want to have employeeLocation List Object inside of it

Comment: Where is your query? How are you getting this data?

Comment: I am using Criteria Api for fetching the data.I am fetching data from Employee table and  along with that i want EmployeeLocation Data too so basically i want to perform join using Criteria. So inorder to peform join i need to have EmployeeLOcation Object inside Employee.But i am not getting the data itself

Comment: Where's your query? HOw are you making the join?

Answer (score 0):

You need to map some `employee` attribute on the `EmployeeLocation` and `JoinColumn` to map the `emp_id`, like this:

```
@Entity
class Employee {
     @Id
     private Integer id;

     @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="employee") // refer to the atribute name of the entity Employee on the EmployeeLocation
     private List<EmployeeLocation> employeeLocation;
     //getters and setters
}

 @Entity
 class EmployeeLocation {

      @Id
      private Integer id;

      @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id") // name of the column on database table
      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
      private Employee employee; 
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution. No Data

Comment: @GauravMasand How do you query it? add this information on your question. This should work.

Comment: I want Employee Object and inside of it i will have EmployeeLocation Object i hope you got waht i am trying to say.